# Ввод чисел в массив с клавиатуры

Tags: python, python-3.x

мне нужно организовать ввод чисел в массив с клавиатуры, но я не знаю, как это сделать. Числа должны быть введены в след формате. Я смотрел интернет, пытался сам, но у меня ничего не получилось

```
1 5
5 6
7 7
```

Comment: и все это в один массив должно быть записано? вы задачу более чётко опишите

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос что сами пробовали делать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так — пользователь окончит свой ввод нажатием на клавишу <kbd>Enter</kbd> после ввода последней строки чисел без того, чтобы что-то задавал:

```
result = []
row = True

while row:
    row = input()
    if row:
        numbers = map(int, row.split())
        result.append(list(numbers))
        
print(result)
```

---

Пример ввода:

> 1 5 <kbd>Enter</kbd>
> 5 6 <kbd>Enter</kbd>
> 7 7 <kbd>Enter</kbd>
> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Выбод:

> ```
> [[1, 5], [5, 6], [7, 7]]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

не понятно, что именно вам надо

ввести в одной строке несколько чисел - это так:

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

ввести в один массив числа из нескольких строк

```
arr = []

for _ in range(3):
    arr += list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ для новичка - ввод последовательности через разделитель. Например, пробел. Пользователь вводит последовательность чисел через пробел, в коде вы получаете строку, которую делите по пробелам и приводите к числу.

Пример исполнения:

```py
raw = input('Введите последовательность чисел через пробел: ')
int_array = [int(i) for i in raw.split(' ') if i.isdigit()]
print(int_array)
```

Ввод

```
Введите последовательность чисел через пробел: 5 48 59 65 33 3   3 2 1
```

Вывод

```
[5, 48, 59, 65, 33, 3, 3, 2, 1]
```

Заметьте, что последовательное указание пробелов не ломает вывод - все числа обработаны корректно.